# Function to return value if a string contains similar values

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have data in two sheets that contain different string values for the same entity.
For example, in Sheet A, a string is entered as "Biology" in A1, but in Sheet B it is entered as "Biology Course".

My goal is to find if the string in Sheet A is located in Sheet B, and then return the value that is in the cell below the string.

In other words if Sheet A looks like this:

| Biology | Blank |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
|  |  |

And Sheet B looks like this:

| Biology Course | Blank |
| --- | --- |
| 200 |  |
| 300 |  |

Then I would like to return the value "200" in Sheet A. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try on-

```
=INDEX(SheetB!A:A,MATCH("*"&A1&"*",SheetB!A:A,0)+1)
```